# SysPrep windows 2012 r2 for VM cloning

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, sysprep, cloning

I'm trying to SysPrep a 2012 r2 std edition VM that I built which has IIS already configured for my website as well as some additional applications already installed and configured the way I need them. I have an unattend file, that I borrowed from an AWS EC2 instance, that I have customized to my settings along with additional settings from other various step by step guides.  However I'm having trouble getting the prep'd image to prompt me for some of the items that are instance specific that I would like to set during the initial boot after being prep'd.

What I would like the initial boot to prompt me for is

1. Computer Name
2. Network settings
3. Joining a domain

Is this possible to do with just SysPrep and the unattend file?  Or does it need to be combined with WAIK/WSIM?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do this:

I create VMs with a PowerShell script as part of the script I copy an existing VHDX with a sysprep'ed OS.

I then mount the VHDX and create a `unattend.xml` as well as a `\Windows\Setup\Scripts\SetupComplete.cmd` file, both are specific to the new VM.

After dismounting the VHDX I can start the VM and everything else is automatic.

Comment: Hi Peter - Is your process for Hyper-V or will it work for VMware too?

Comment: I only use Hyper-V. I don't know anything about VMware, it's easy a mount a VHDX under Windows, I don't know whether the can do the same with the VMware virtual disks.